# How to identify xml element with no values in any attributes or sub-elements?

Tags: java, xml

We are dynamically creating xml using jaxb in java.

We create and add numerous elements to the root element.

Assume the elements are

a1,
a2,
a3,
...

a1 has sub-elements as well as many attributes. similarly a2, a3

assume if a1 has no values in any of his attributes and elements we should not add the element at all to the root.

currently we are checking for null for each and every attribute and finally deciding whether to add that element or not.

Is there an API to identify whether the given element has only empty sub-elements and attributes?

Example,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
<book id="bk101">
  <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
  <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
  <genre>Computer</genre>
  <price>44.95</price>
  <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
  <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
  with XML.</description>
</book>
<book id="">
  <author></author>
  <title></title>
  <genre></genre>
  <price></price>
  <publish_date></publish_date>
  <description></description>
</book>
<book id="">
  <author>Corets, Eva</author>
  <title></title>
  <genre></genre>
  <price></price>
  <publish_date></publish_date>
  <description></description>
</book>
<book id="bk104">
  <author></author>
  <title></title>
  <genre></genre>
  <price></price>
  <publish_date></publish_date>
  <description></description>
</book>
<book id="">
  <author></author>
  <title></title>
  <genre></genre>
  <price></price>
  <publish_date></publish_date>
  <description>The two daughters of Maeve, half-sisters, 
  battle one another for control of England. Sequel to 
  Oberon's Legacy.</description>
</book>
</catalog>
```

Comment: It would help if you'd show sample *XML* rather than just a list of identifiers.

Comment: please kindly go through the above XML

Comment: So now you've given us sample XML, but not told us which elements you'd expect to pick out. I assume it's the `author` ones etc later? What about an empty string as an attribute value? Which API are you using to parse the XML? (There are lots available...) Can you post a short but complete program demonstrating the code you've got so far, and where it goes wrong?

Comment: In the above example, i want to skip the second element as it doesn't have any value in elements as well as in attributes. so i need a method or API in any java third party library to verify.

Comment: Well you shouldn't expect there to be a single method that does exactly what you want. You're going to need to write the method yourself - have you tried doing that yet? What does it look like? What went wrong?

Comment: You use jaxb : objects => XML, then you have to re-parse it, to clean it. Not very efficient. If your datas are only like this (book, author, ...), why not directly generate yourself the XML, reading the objects ? (not too hard in that way).

Answer (score 0):

XML does it:

```
String xml=""; // YOUR XML HERE, you can also load if from file

DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory =DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
builderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
// PARSE
Document document = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));

// ALL NODES SECOND LEVEL
XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
String expression="/*/*";

NodeList nodes  = (NodeList)  xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);

// Iterate ...
for(int i=0; i<nodes.getLength(); i++)
{
 Node the_node = nodes.item(i);

 if(the_node instanceof Element)
    {
    Element element=(Element) the_node;

    // CONTENT: VOID ?
    String content_trimed=element.getTextContent().trim();

    // NOT THIS !
    if (content_trimed.length()>0) continue;

    // ATTRIBUTES
    boolean to_delete=true; // default

    NamedNodeMap attributes=element.getAttributes();
    for (int k=0;k<attributes.getLength();k++)
        {
        String value=attributes.item(k).getNodeValue();
        if (!value.equals("")) to_delete=false;
        }

    if (!to_delete) continue;

    // OK : DELETE THIS !!!
    Node father=the_node.getParentNode();
    father.removeChild(the_node);
    }

}

// XML => STRING
TransformerFactory transFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transFactory.newTransformer();
StringWriter buffer = new StringWriter();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
transformer.transform(new DOMSource(document),new StreamResult(buffer));
String out = buffer.toString();
System.out.println("HIERARCHY"+out);

// STORE IT: EXERCICE
```